# Object-fit: cover; alternative?

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image on my page that I want to keep the ratio of but resize according to screen size. I would like it so that the smaller of the width and height is made to fit the element exactly, and the larger dimension overflows the element.

I found the

```
object-fit: cover;
```

style which would suit my needs but very quickly found out that support for this is extremely limited (pretty much opera only). Is there anything else I can use to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're able to add this image to the page as a background, then you can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This property can also accept `contain` value. Experiment with both a bit and you'll see the difference.

`cover` forces the image to **fill** the whole container. It means the image will be cropped if its ratio doesn't match the container's ratio.
`contain` forces the image to **fit** in the container. It means that image will never go out the bounds of the container. If ratios (image and container) are different, there will be blank spaces on the sides of the image (left & right or top & bottom).

`cover` and `contain` values are supported accordingly:

```
Chrome    Firefox   IE    Opera    Safari
3.0       3.6       9.0   10.0     4.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I feel like such an idiot, didn't even think about applying the image as a background to the div and then using 'background-size: cover;' . Thanks a bunch for your help and answer :)

Comment: I wrote a micro library that applies a fix for all values of `object-fit` to many browsers automatically: https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/

Comment: Dont forget to add: "background-position: center" so it maintains the image centered just like "object-fit: cover".

Answer (score 11):

I had similar issue. I resolved it with **just CSS**.

Basically `Object-fit: cover` was not working in IE and it was taking 100% width and 100% height and aspect ratio was distorted. In other words image zooming effect wasn't there which I was seeing in chrome.

The approach I took was to position the image inside the container with  **absolute** and then **place it right at the centre** using the combination:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Once it is in the centre, I give to the image,

```
// For vertical blocks (i.e., where height is greater than width)
height: 100%;
width: auto;

// For Horizontal blocks (i.e., where width is greater than height)
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

This makes the image get the effect of Object-fit:cover.

---

## Here is a demonstration of the above logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/furqan_694/s3xLe1gp/

This logic works in all browsers.

Comment: Worth mention that this solution introduces a slightly blur in the images

Comment: @JoãoAlves It purely depends on your image resolution if I am not wrong. If otherwise, then I'm curious to learn why. Please share your findings.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168045/1424951 helps to understand why. I was going for your solution and noticed this blur, so I just wanted to let others know what I faced!

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing. But that adds an additional complicated answer which might not be needed in all cases though. But quite interesting. I hadn't noticed the blur earlier.