# Alternative to Object-fit:cover;

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Object-fit:cover is not working on IE. It works just fine on pretty much all the other browsers that I tried. Is there a way to make IE look the same.

I found this:
[Object-fit: cover; alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717622/object-fit-cover-alternative)

However, adding the image to the background is unfortunately not an option for us.