# CSS translate with percentage causes blurred image

Tags: html, css, sass

I've encountered this very annoying problem.

When you align an image with transform, translate percentage based it causes the image to blur slightly. This is only with **percentage** alignment

Consider this css:

```
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: translate(1%,1%); 
}
```

Tried solutions:

1. translate3d fix
2. perspective fix
3. translateZ fix

Maybe somebody has an solution?

[Updated: Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsvbbucL/1/)
I updated the js fiddle with an image to better see the difference. It is very noticeable in photography.

**Example image:**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: @user4584963 unfortunately not. I know now its a retina ( or another high resolution ) screen specific problem. This causes it to be overlooked I think, not all users can see the difference because of the lower resolution. Do you see the problem too?

Comment: Ya it's not always blurry but I can see as I change the width and/or height of the browser window the blurriness comes and goes.

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this
`translateX(calc(-50% + 0.5px))`

Comment: This will work only if the "remainer" is exactly 0.5px. Which is not always something you can know in advance. So it's not a good solution.

Comment: for me it worked

Answer (score 2):

Using a percentage value with Transform: translate means it positions your element with sub-pixel accuracy. You can see the pixel-value offset of your second div in the jsfiddle when you query it in the console:

[image: subpixel positioning]

This means that your browser is forced to do some less than optimal anti-aliasing to position your image, and that's what's causing the blurriness. If you could position it to whole-pixel values instead the image would remain sharp.

I haven't found an elegant solution to this annoying problem, but with javascript (sorry, I know this is tagged as a css problem) it's conceivable you could measure the element's offset values, then remove the translate and measure the non-translated pixel offset values and then calculate the difference between the two offsets (difference in offset between pre and post translate). Then rather than putting translate(%, %) back onto your element you could round the differences you calculated to the nearest whole pixel value (ie: remove sub-pixel rendering) and then reapply those values as translate (px, px) instead. This would keep your image sharp. It's a less than optimal solution, but it's the best I've been able to come up with so far.

EDIT:

Here's a quick function I wrote that will do what I'm talking about above. Once again, I apologize that this is not a CSS solution, but I see no way to fix it with CSS. This is also not a great solution in that you lose the responsiveness of % values, and it will also overwrite any Transform attributes that aren't translateX or translateY (so maybe use a wrapper div if that's a problem). Somebody could probably solve that problem by doing this with a Transform matrix, but yeah...

[EDIT 2: updated function to account for any css transitions that may be assigned to element]

```js
function snapTranslateXYValsToNearestPixel(element){
  var xTransPos = $(element).offset().left;
  var yTransPos = $(element).offset().top;
  // turn off any transitions (but save values first):
  var transitionVal = $(element).css('transition');
  $(element).css('transition', 'none');
  // turn off translate:
  $(element).css('transform', 'translateX(0) translateY(0)');
  var xPosDiff = xTransPos - $(element).offset().left;
  var yPosDiff = yTransPos - $(element).offset().top;
  var xPixelVal = Math.round(xPosDiff);
  var yPixelVal = Math.round(yPosDiff);
  var translateVal = 'translateX(' + xPixelVal + 'px) translateY(' + yPixelVal + 'px)';
  $(element).css('transform', translateVal);
  // reapply transition value (wait one tick for new css value to apply first):
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(element).css('transition', transitionVal);
  }, 1);
}
```

Again, not a totally ideal solution... BUT it WILL convert the translateX and translateY percentages of your element to whole pixel values and it will give you a nice crisp image.

Example usage:

```
snapTranslateXYValsToNearestPixel('.align-per');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with an overlay which moves to the middle of the window via CSS and the content determines the height and width. The overlay also has a maximum height and width.
Besides, I got some CSS transitions on the overlay I didn't want to lose.

All CSS fixes described here did not work.

I got rid of the blur by using JavaScript to ensure that the overlay is always divisible by 2. I call this function when creating the overlay, as well as when resizing the window.

Theoretically, the overlay works without JS - but with JS it's sharper. And it do not need any timeouts to keep the transitions work.

```
fullPixelFix = function() {
  var overlay = $('#overlay');
  overlay.removeAttr('style');
  var dividable_width = Math.round(overlay.outerWidth() / 2) * 2;
  var dividable_height = Math.round(overlay.outerHeight() / 2) * 2;
  overlay.outerWidth(dividable_width).outerHeight(dividable_height);
  overlay.css(maxWidth: dividable_width, maxHeight: dividable_height);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this fix here : [CSS: transform: translate(-50%, -50%) makes texts blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109299/css-transform-translate-50-50-makes-texts-blurry)

```
div.align-per {
  transform: translate(1%, 1%) translateZ(0) ;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

I think it's worth investigating for others browsers.

Comment: @371 Thanks for your message. 

Unfortunately the ` -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);` resets the transform value. If you adjust it to:

` -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translate(1%, 1%);` 

you will see the image stays blurred.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't tell if it's blurred and I can't see it or if it's not blurred anymore. Could you confirm that in this picture, the first one is not blurred and the other two are? http://i.imgur.com/E4pypZD.png

Comment: I can confirm that the middle one is more blurred. I know it is very suble, but in photography very noticeable.

Comment: The problem is actually due to sub-pixel placement of the element. This css trick (along with other common ones like backface-visibility) unfortunately won't fix this. :/