# Alternative to object-fit with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf, object-fit

I am currently trying to export html pages to pdf using wkhtmltopdf, but the `object-fit` I use to force my images into a square doesn't work; the images end up stretched to fit the square box instead of being cropped properly.

I know for a fact that `object-fit` doesn't work with wkhtmltopdf, and I've been looking for workarounds (cf [Object-fit: cover; alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19717622/object-fit-cover-alternative) ) but :

- I cannot access the image directly since it's used in a template (for the background method)
- I have no easy way to differentiate between horizontal or vertical images

here's the current snippet I have that *doesn't work* (works fine on the html though):

```
  .class .img-box {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .class .img-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

I'm at the point where I start getting a little upset by this, so if anyone knows about a working solution, I'd be glad to know about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 100%;background-image: url();background-size: contain;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).